# Checking Kafka consumer group liveliness in java code

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have written a java code for Kafka consumer using executor service which will run 24/7 consume the data and process it.

But in some scenarios like due to Kafka coordinator broker node went down, job will fail i.e., consumer group will become dead and i will not able to know it and the java jar would be running but not doing anything.

```
 INFO [2018-11-07 03:25:58,425] [pool-1-thread-1] (AbstractCoordinator.java:coordinatorDead) - Marking the coordinator broker_host (id: 2147483446 rack: null) dead for group group_name
 INFO [2018-11-07 03:26:10,817] [pool-1-thread-1] (AbstractCoordinator.java:onSuccess) - Discovered coordinator broker_host (id: 2147483446 rack: null) for group group_name.
```

I want to check the Kafka consumer liveliness in java code periodically. So, if Kafka consumer group becomes dead, i will be able to make it live or trigger the mail and kill the job.

Can anyone provide any input on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the broker acting as coordinator for your consumer group goes down, each consumer in the group will find which remaining broker is to become the new coordinator for their group. This scenario should not be fatal to your group.

However, monitoring consumer groups is still a very common thing to do in order to track lag, scale in/out if needed or just ensure an important job is actually running!

The easiest way is to use the AdminClient APIs, especially:

- [`describeConsumerGroups()`](http://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#describeConsumerGroups-java.util.Collection-): This lists the members and the overal state of the group
- [`listConsumerGroupOffsets()`](http://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#listConsumerGroupOffsets-java.lang.String-): This lists the current offsets

Alternatively you can run the `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` tool to retrieve details about groups. That displays the current position, lag and client ids or members.

Comment: I am using kafka API 0.11.0.0 version, for AdminClient object i doesn't get above two methods. Do i need to upgrade the API version or is it deprecated? I see describeCluster() for AdminClient object.

Comment: These APIs are only available in AdminClient 2.0.0 and above. On the server side Kafka 0.11 is enough to get these working

Comment: I can't upgrade the API to 2.0.0, as it would require much change in consumer code. Is there any thing i can do to achieve the task?

Comment: Which version are you using? The Consumer API has not changed in years and has kept binary compatibility throughout

Comment: I am using kafka-client 0.11.0.0 API, for admin client do I need to use any other dependency?

Comment: Yes you need kafka-client 2.0.0 or above

Comment: Is there any other way to check the consumer group liveliness as i can't upgrade to kafka-client 2.0.0

Comment: You can also use the kafka-consumer-groups tool. I've updated my answer to include it

Comment: We have upgraded the kafka broker to kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0, Hope now we can use the kafka-client 2.0.0 right?

Comment: I _think_ that should be enough. It's not something I've tried recently though so give it a go and see what happens. Also if this answer helped or solved your issue, feel free to accept or upvote.

Comment: @MickaelMaison Is it possible to know each consumer instance status in consumer group ? Also if yes how would we know when it was last active in case the instance died ?

Comment: @MickaelMaison If it is not possible to know per each consumer instance would it be possible to know when the consumer group was last active ? Currently admin api has consumer group state but I was wondering if there is easy way to know what time the consumer group died.